# include javascript code block in javascript keyup function

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to include a javascript snippet/code in javascript, for example if i type

**apalak**, the word should replace itself as in the snippet/code. (word_file.js) I tried to link the snippet js file but it doesn't work so i copied the code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {
  
  var text2 = $(this).val();
  
  test();
  
  $("#ta_2").val(text2);
 
})
});

/*
///word_file.js

function test()
{
 text2 = text2.replace(/abıca/g, "aBıçaZZZ"); 
 text2 = text2.replace(/abrık/g, "aBRQZZZ"); 
 text2 = text2.replace(/apşak/g, "apşqZZZ"); 
 text2 = text2.replace(/abbak/g, "aBBqZZZ"); 
 text2 = text2.replace(/aparma/g, "apRmaZZZ"); 
 text2 = text2.replace(/apalisına/g, "apLiSıNaZZZ"); 
 text2 = text2.replace(/appak/g, "appqZZZ"); 
 text2 = text2.replace(/aparmadutı/g, "apRmDuTıZZZ"); 
 text2 = text2.replace(/apışık/g, "apışQZZZ"); 
 text2 = text2.replace(/apışıklık/g, "apışQLQZZZ"); 
 text2 = text2.replace(/apalak/g, "apLqZZZ"); 



}


*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body>
  
<textarea id="ta_1"   rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>
       
<textarea id="ta_2"   rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the function is not working or not seen not calling

Comment: Add `return text2;` at the bottom of the file. and in `keyup` handler add `$("#ta_2").val(test(text2));`

Comment: If you don't get any 404 error in your console.log then try what @Tushar said it should work

Comment: Hmm... `text2` is a local variable in the `keyup`'s callback function. `test()` can't access that.

Comment: i think that's why ClasG .. what should i do ?

Comment: now it's working, i just removed the "var" thanks ;) ClasG

Comment: its's a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
<textarea id="ta_2" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>

<script>
$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {

  var text2 = $(this).val();

  text2 = test(text2);

  $("#ta_2").val(text2);
});

function test(text2)
{
    text2 = text2.replace(/abica/g, "aBiçaZZZ"); 
    text2 = text2.replace(/abrik/g, "aBRQZZZ"); 
    text2 = text2.replace(/apsak/g, "apsqZZZ"); 
    text2 = text2.replace(/abbak/g, "aBBqZZZ"); 
    text2 = text2.replace(/aparma/g, "apRmaZZZ"); 
    text2 = text2.replace(/apalisina/g, "apLiSiNaZZZ"); 
    text2 = text2.replace(/appak/g, "appqZZZ"); 
    text2 = text2.replace(/aparmaduti/g, "apRmDuTiZZZ"); 
    text2 = text2.replace(/apisik/g, "apisQZZZ"); 
    text2 = text2.replace(/apisiklik/g, "apisQLQZZZ"); 
    text2 = text2.replace(/apalak/g, "apLqZZZ");

    return text2;
}
</script>
```